# How can I measure the speed between laptop and wireless access point?

Tags: networking, router, wifi

How can I measure the speed between my laptop and the wireless access point it’s connected to?

Notes:

- when measuring the speed of the general connection to the internet, I’d use something like speedtest.net, but I’m not sure how to measure the speed *just* between laptop and WAP?
- In case it’s relevant, the reason I would like to measure this is because I’m trying to determine what speed I’ll get between two devices on the same local network, but I haven’t purchased the second device yet, so I can’t test between the two devices, but figure I can get an approximate estimate by measuring the throughput/latency of one device on the network

Comment: use a tool like iperf

Answer (score 1):

I this case, you need to measure the speed between two local devices in the same network, connected to the same router/wifi/access-point.

Just get a tool to measure network speed for local networks and run it.

Please take a look at this blog post:
[https://www.raymond.cc/blog/network-benchmark-test-your-network-speed/][1]

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the reported Ethernet link speed. All current hardware runs bridged/switched data at wire speed, no need to actually measure.

More relevant is the effective Wi-fi throughput *across the WAP*, of course.

For any other device, throughput can widely vary, depending on the hardware/software and the workload - check the spec sheet. Switches are generally wire speed (unless you've got a really large chassis or a bunch of 40G+ ports).